# Do i need to convert categorical variable to factor type for CART?

Tags: r

i have a dataset with:
gender: 0 - female, 1 - male
cancer : 0 - no, 1 - yes
etc

do I need to convert these to factor datatype?
I need to explore these data to come up graphs and lastly, use CART R.
thank you!

Comment: Binary? no. More categories? yes.

Comment: yes, there are more categories including continuous variables.  which method would u recommend for CART)? (method=anova is for continuous variables ) but my dataset will have both continuous and factor datatypes, so im unsure abt that, thankyou v much!

Comment: Ask statistical methodology questions on stats.stackexchange, not stack overflow.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.